# Can I pass two functions in array.foreach

Tags: javascript, mongodb, callback, cursor

I read a perfectly running code recently in which two functions are passed in array.foreach for a mongo cursor. I would like to know the proper working of this code.

```
    var myArray = [];
    mongoCursor.forEach(function(element) {
      myArray.push(element);
    }, () => {
      console.log(myArray.length);
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't misread it? The error callback could have been a part of a promise, and the `forEach` was inside the success callback.

Comment: You can't *exactly* pass two functions. The second would be used as the `this` argument for the first but this is not actually employed here.

Comment: [Array.foreach](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.foreach) the code you see is wrong.

Comment: What if the array is a mongo cursor?

Comment: @ShamlikhanCP Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. `Array.forEach()` method gets only one callback function. Read MDN's [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

You can pass second argument `thisArg` and that would be a context of the callback. Next example should show you the point (I hope):

```js
const someObject = { title: 'someObject' };
[1,2].forEach(function(item) { 
 console.log(item);
 console.log(this.title);
}, someObject)
```

If you are talking about the mongo cursor, then you can use something like you wrote if you are working with [Node.js MongoDB Driver API](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#forEach)

Comment: Again, the second function would be used as the `this` context of the first. This *could* be useful but not in OP's example, as `this` isn't ever used.

Comment: What if the array binded to foreach is a mongo cursor?